# How can I update only images dynamically in a page from our database in java without disturbing the content of the rest of the page?

Tags: java, javascript

How can I update only images dynamically in a page from our database in java without disturbing the content of the rest of the page ?

Comment: It depends where the another image lies. Still, just replace the `src` content of your `<img>` by using javascript.

Answer (score 0):

1. Write a Servlet which will pull appropriate image from database
   based on some request parameter and return to browser.
2. Put the url of the servlet in the "src" of your image tag in html.
3. Use JavaScript to change the image src whenever required.